# how to flip a cube in air using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using three.js framework and using physi.js for forces and gravity. My problem is that i has given some position to a dice on a plane and want to lob it or flip it from its position with some angle by clicking on it such that it rotate in air and fall on plane due to gravity force of plane.
i have idea about onclickevent method but i don't know how to set the dice to jump with some height in 90 degree and rotate it with some angle only one time for one click.

if you have some suggestion please give me method to set up the dice
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have no experience with physi.js, for physics i use cannon.js, so i do have some experience with physics. i can tell you how it's done, but i cant provide an example just yet. the first thing you need to do is [cast a ray](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Raycaster) from the camera to the dice. This tells you if the object is clicked on. from there you apply a force to where the object is clicked. i hope this helps.

EDIT/Follow up:
I've been looking over physi.js, and it seems pretty similar to cannon.js. Also, there are many aspects to what you're asking, but i'll try to be as comprehensive as possible.

The first thing to do is set the gravity. In the examples it is done by:

```
var scene = new Physijs.Scene({ fixedTimeStep: 1 / 120 });
scene.setGravity(new THREE.Vector3( 0, -30, 0 ));
```

the next thing to do is define the plane the dice is sitting on as a rigid body, and the dice as a rigid body.

```
var dice = new Physijs.BoxMesh(
    new THREE.CubeGeometry(5, 5, 5), //the collision geometry
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/dicetexture.jpg' )});, // material of the dice
    5, // mass, for the plane use 0, meaning it doesnt move.
    { restitution: .2, friction: .8 } //contact material
);
```

and finally, you need to apply a force, i cant find an example of it, but going over the [source](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/blob/master/physi.js) real quick, i found:

```
// Physijs.Mesh.applyForce
Physijs.Mesh.prototype.applyForce = function ( force, offset ) {
    if ( this.world ) {
        this.world.execute( 'applyForce', { id: this._physijs.id, force_x: force.x, force_y : force.y, force_z : force.z, x: offset.x, y: offset.y, z: offset.z } );
    }
};
```

both `force` and `offset` should be vectors. `force` being the direction and magnitude, `offset` being the point of origin.

i'll experiment a bit more with physi.js it seems to have solved some problems i've been pondering with. if this still doesnt solve the problem. i'll post an example.

as for letting it spin for a set number of times in a preset height, i think that's a lot of experimenting with the values...

EDIT 2:

In the fiddle you posted the problem you explained was an undefined variable, `effect`.

```
if (intersects.length > 0) {
    intersects[ 0 ].applyImpulse(effect, offset);
}
```

change this to:

```
if (intersects.length > 0) {
    var effect = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 100, 0 );
    var offset = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
    intersects[ 0 ].object.applyImpulse(effect, offset);
}
```

the values ARE defined, but you define them in a different function.

```
function apply_force(){
    var effect = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 100, 0 );
    var offset = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
    object.applyImpulse( effect, offset );
 }
```

this function will not be used anymore, so you might as well remove it.

CLICK TIMER:

```
if(canClick == true){
    //process click
    canClick = false;
    setTimeout(function(){canClick = true}, 5000)//5 seconds before the user can click again.
}
```

Comment: no any action same error.. but i replace by intersects[ 0 ].object.applyImpulse(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 100, 0 ),new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 )); and its work

Comment: try playing a bit with the offset vector for the rotation. you could check if the object has a velocity, if it doesnt, give it the impulse.

Comment: sorry for late reply i had done it thanks for your suggestion.. now i have to apply condition for lock the dice after one click.

Comment: and also how to give name to the faces of dice.. it is quite difficult i think.. in js file of model it shows 2500 faces..

Comment: yaa.. do you know how to give no. to the faces of loaded dice model.. because js file of model showing 10000 faces. can you help?

Comment: like rolling dice show 2 no. then outcome will be 2. it is possible to set face with loaded model?

Comment: i had applied addeventlistner() method to control the double click. but didn't succeed. I will check later firstly I need to solve above problem

Comment: which is a different problem. please put this one as answered and make a new question.

Comment: kevin can you tell me how to lock the dice with 1st click such that  2nd or 3rd click over the dice doesnot effect. I mean to say how to apply condition with raycaster to avoid double click over a dice and as well as right click

Comment: there are several ways, you could check if the dice has velocity, or simply add a timer to make sure `n` seconds is between clicks. see above for example.

Comment: actually raycaster gives only this function if(intersects.length>0){} to activate click method with the object. how can i add else{} method with it to prevent user for another click? i try to apply canClick method that doesnot effect. is there any requirement to update  it? check http://jsfiddle.net/m099debd/1/

Comment: and what function ensure that the dice had been drawn. am i need any collider? to check

Comment: do you have skype? i feel like this would be easyer over skype. stackoverflow doesnt like long discussions in the comments. if so, just add me.

Comment: thank you for your concern. i will be very greatfull of you. Sorry i am not accessible to skype account having some trouble and also null balance. can we chat over social site or gmail?

Comment: sure what's your user name? my is shoaib lovesfrnd